# Rails, Capistrano, and Dreamhost -- Key Verification Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, dreamhost, ssh-keys

I'm trying to setup my Rails app on Dreamhost and I'm at the stage of trying to get Capistrano setup.

I have a git server setup on the same server as where I'm deploying. I have my SSH keys setup (I think) -- at least I can SSH in no problem.

Both 'cap deploy:setup' and 'cap deploy:check' run without error.

But then when I try to run 'cap deploy:migrations' I get the following:

```
* executing `deploy:migrations'
* executing `deploy:update_code'
 updating the cached checkout on all servers
 executing locally: "git ls-remote user@server.dreamhost.com:git/project.git master"
 command finished in 1065ms
* executing "if [ -d /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags  origin && git reset  --hard 406475489f2934554f5b80cf17e44576ba7ee02f && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone user@domain.dreamhost.com:git/project.git /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -b deploy 406475489f2934554f5b80cf17e44576ba7ee02f; fi"
servers: ["server.dreamhost.com"]
[server.dreamhost.com] executing command
** [server.dreamhost.com :: out] Cloning into /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy...
```

Here's where the problem is:

```
** [server.dreamhost.com :: err] Host key verification failed.
** [server.dreamhost.com :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
command finished in 157ms
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags  origin && git reset  --hard 406475489f2934554f5b80cf17e44576ba7ee02f && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone user@server.dreamhost.com:git/project.git /home/user/domain.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/user/domain.com/shared
```

I've erased my keys and created new ones (again, SSH'ing into the server works fine) to no avail. This is probably a really basic misunderstanding on my part, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts** on the dreamhost server and try again. The server is accessing itself when clonding from *user@server.dreamhost.com:git/project.git*.

It the IP of this server changed you will run into that kind of problems.

Comment: I have **/.ssh/authorized_keys** but no **known_hosts** file. Are these files the same thing or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's not the same. authorized_keys contains a list of public ssh keys that are allowed to connect without providing a password. known_hosts is a file that tracks name/ip address pairs of all servers that have been connected to vis ssh. This prevents dns spoofing. If the ip address changes from a hostname ssh is throwing an error the same you see in your log. Can you try to connect from your server to your server pls? Run _ssh user@server.dreamhost.com_ on the server.  Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have an identical setup & have been stymied at the same point in the deployment. In order to finish the investigation, I will add the following details:

on dreamhost server (home/user/.ssh/): authorized_keys and id_rsa.

```
ssh user@server.dreamhost.com = no problem, but I was asked to verify key authenticity.

cap deploy:setup = no problems.
cap deploy:check = no problems.
cap deploy:migrations = failure (host key verification.)
```

Comment: bjpcjp - ever figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

1) SSH into Dreamhost

2) `> ssh bitbucket.org`

You will see something like:

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.168)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

3) Type in "yes"

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,131.103.20.168' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

Now bitbucket.org is correctly added to `.known_hosts`.